# What is the difference between apt-cache show and apt-cache showpkg?

Tags: linux

The only difference I can spot is that the command `apt-cache show package_name` displays the description of package. Is there a specific reason I would use one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`show` provides the package details for the package, so name, version, description and various  technical information.

`showpkg` provides information regarding `dependencies` (ie what this package needs to already be installed to function) `reverse dependencies` (what other packages rely on this one) and `provides` which says what function the package provides.  An example of this would be providing `syslog` capability:

Lets say you have a package `foobar` that needs syslog running in order to run.  You could install `syslogd`, `syslog-ng` or `syslog-flibble`.  If each of these 'provide'  syslog, then `foobar` can run regardless of exactly which one is installed.

Unless you are troubleshooting a dependency issue, then `show` usually provides the most useful information.

Comment: Thanks Paul. When you say `reverse dependencies`, do you mean packages that rely on the package I am querying about. For example if I run the command `sudo apt-cache showpkg skype`, it would show its reverse dependencies i.e. packages that rely on skype. Don't quite follow what you mean by `provides`.

Comment: Well the explanation for `provides` is above in the answer, but the point is that this is extra information that `showpkg` displays that `show` does not, as per your question.  If you need any of this information, then you need to use `showpkg` rather than `show`.  And yes, a reverse dependency is a package that has this one listed as a dependency.

Comment: So when you say listed dependency, does it list all the packages that rely on say skype? Sorry haven't come across a package that lists reverse dependencies as of yet.